# Unable to create a archive build for Any iOS Device (arm64, armv7)

Tags: ios

Product: Video SDKEnvironment: iOSSDK Version: v3.5.0.

I am trying a archive build with `Build="Any iOS Device (arm64, armv7)"`. The build fails with

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FlipperKitNetworkPlugin", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SKIOSNetworkAdapter", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FlipperKitReactPlugin", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FKUserDefaultsPlugin", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FlipperKitLayoutPlugin", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SKDescriptorMapper", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FlipperClient", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I could do device specific build (like `arm64`) and deploy to my iPhone and test it. That works.

But here, I'm trying to create an archive build so I can push the build to other registered iPhone devices of other team members.

Comment: Do you really want to build for armv7?

Comment: No, my goal is to get a successful archive build, but to create an archive build, the only option presented to me by XCode is Any iOS Device (arm64, armv7). Is there a way i can create archive build with just arm64?